# How to do Pandas stacked bar chart on number line instead of categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart where the x-axis is based on a regular number line instead of categories. Maybe bar chart is not the right term?

How can I make the stacked bars, but have the x number line be spaced "normally" (with a big relative gap between 5.0 and 10.6)? I also want to set a regular tick interval, instead of having every bar labeled. (The real dataset is dense but with some spurious gaps, and I want to use the bar colors to qualitatively show changes as a function of x.)

```
fid = ["name", "name", "name", "name", "name"]
x = [1.02, 1.3, 2, 5, 10.6]
y1 = [0, 1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1]
y2 = [0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4]
y3 = [0.7, 0, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(fid, x, y1, y2, y3), columns=["fid", "x", "y1", "y2", "y3"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.bar(x="x", stacked=True, ax=ax)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by " I want to use the bar colors to qualitatively show changes as a function of x.".  Could you please take a look at my answer below and see if that's the plot you wanted in your question ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a matplotlib bar chart, the `x` values are treated as categorical data, so matplotlib always plots it along `range(0, ...)` and relabels the ticks with the `x` values.

To scale the bar distances, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the `x` values to have filler rows between the real data points:

```
start, stop = 0, 16
xstep = 0.01
tickstep = 2

xfill = np.round(np.arange(start, stop + xstep, xstep), 2)
out = df.set_index("x").reindex(xfill).reset_index()

ax = out.plot.bar(x="x", stacked=True, width=20, figsize=(10, 3))
xticklabels = np.arange(start, stop+tickstep, tickstep).astype(float)
xticks = out.index[out.x.isin(xticklabels)]
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
```

[image: bar plot on number line]

---

#### Details

1. Generate the `xfill` as `[0, 0.01, 0.02, ...]`. I've tried to make this portable by extracting the max number of decimals from `x`, but float precision is always tricky so this may need to be tweaked:

   ```
   decimals = df.x.astype(str).str.split(".").str[-1].str.len().max()
   xstep = 10.0 ** -decimals
   start = 0
   stop = 16

   xfill = np.round(np.arange(start, stop + xstep, xstep), decimals)
   # array([ 0.  ,  0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05,  ...])
   ```
2. [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the `x` column against this new `xfill`, so the filler rows will be NaN:

   ```
   out = df.set_index("x").reindex(xfill).reset_index()
   #     x   fid   y1   y2   y3
   #  0.00   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...
   #  1.01   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #  1.02  name  0.0  0.3  0.7
   #  1.03   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...
   #  1.29   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #  1.30  name  1.0  0.0  0.0
   #  1.31   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...
   #  1.99   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #  2.00  name  0.2  0.1  0.7
   #  2.01   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...
   #  4.99   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #  5.00  name  0.6  0.1  0.3
   #  5.01   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...
   # 10.59   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   # 10.60  name  0.1  0.4  0.5
   # 10.61   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   #   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...
   # 16.00   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   ```
3. Plot the reindexed data (with `xticks` spaced apart by `tickstep`):

   ```
   ax = out.plot.bar(x="x", stacked=True, width=20, figsize=(10, 3))

   tickstep = 2
   xticklabels = np.arange(start, stop + tickstep, tickstep).astype(float)
   xticks = out.index[out.x.isin(xticklabels)]
   ax.set_xticks(xticks)
   ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)

   plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
   ```

---

Combined code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"fid": ["name", "name", "name", "name", "name"], "x": [1.02, 1.3, 2, 5, 10.6], "y1": [0, 1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1], "y2": [0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4], "y3": [0.7, 0, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5]})

decimals = df.x.astype(str).str.split(".").str[-1].str.len().max()
xstep = 10.0 ** -decimals
start = 0
stop = 16

xfill = np.round(np.arange(start, stop + xstep, xstep), decimals)
out = df.set_index("x").reindex(xfill).reset_index()
ax = out.plot.bar(x="x", stacked=True, width=20, figsize=(10, 3))

tickstep = 2
xticklabels = np.arange(start, stop + tickstep, tickstep).astype(float)
xticks = out.index[out.x.isin(xticklabels)]
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
```

Comment: indeed https://imgur.com/a/D7L5GII

Comment: @a11 Updated to set both `xticks` and `xticklabels`. I'm not sure why it's not needed on my side (maybe different version?), but it should fix the issue on your end.

Comment: that did it, thanks! It says I have to wait 5 more hours to award the bounty, so I will do that then. thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

My answer below illustrates how the stacking with spacing can be done.  You can adopt the solution and tailor the function to your needs, eg you don't need to use itertools, just use a regular counter will do. You can also tailor the arguments as needed.

The idea behind the solution:

1. using cumsum to calculate the stacking
2. use matplotlib to plot a bar (instead of stack) and use the zorder to control which is infront.

Function

```
from itertools import count
from math import floor

def plt_stack_spacing( df , figsize=(10,6) , width=0.2 , bb_anchor=(1.05,1)):

    ycol = df.columns[2:]
    df1 = df.iloc[:,[0,1]]
    df1 = df1.join(df[ycol].cumsum(axis=1))
    
    c = count(0,-1)  # either itertools.count or manuall adjust the number c+=1
    
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    for col in ycol:
        plt.bar(df1.x,df1[col],label=col,width=width,zorder=next(c))

    xmin = floor(df.x.min())
    xmax = floor(df.x.max())
    xt = [*range(xmin,xmax+2)]
    
    plt.xticks(xt)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=bb_anchor, loc=2)
    plt.show();
```

Calling the function:

```
plt_stack_spacing(df,(18,5),0.2,(1.01,1))
```

Output:

[image]

Benchmark: Timing of 100 plots of 300 rows and 4 columns (y1,y2,y3,y4) = 225 secs = 3.75 min **without** enhancements.

[image]

Comment: this seems to be working, but it is very slow on a dataset of 300 x-values and 4 y columns, and that is one of my smaller datasets. I think that is because it doesn't use stack, so it has to create everything over and over again

Comment: @a11 How long it took ?  Able to pass your dataset for me to do a test ?

Comment: cannot share data. You can recreate it with random numbers (300 x values, 4 y columns). I stopped after 4 mins, as I have to do this over 100 times with datasets larger than this one. Beefy computer, first time I've run into comp speed issues.

Comment: Ok.  I gen my data and try.

Comment: @a11 another question is that are you using the dataframe for plotting only ?  If you read the dataframe and when I plot, the values in the dataframe is updated for the plot, is this ok ?

Comment: @a11 hi ! I've updated the answer. I've done a benchmark on 100 plots of 300 rows vs 4 columns as shown without enhancements. The timing is about 3.75 min. Is this the timing you talking about 4 min ? Or the 4 min is for 1 file ?